# Horizontal Divider Carved Lines

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to achieve horizontal dividing that looks like carved lines in CSS3.

I've tried

```
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Messed around with some colors and opacity but I just cannot seem to get the right combination. I can do this on photoshop easily.
What i'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. You know, you can embed images in your question - so we don't have to click a link to go offsite (which is something that most answerers prefer not to have to do). It also means that the link will not go stale, and people can come back to see your question (and it's eventual solution) for all time. Also - it'd help if you showed/told us what was wrong with the one you tried (so we don't have to load/run your code in our systems, but can just give you an answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `border-top` and `border-bottom` properties, you could set the values separately.
For instance:

```css
hr {
    border: 0; /* reset the default stylesheet */
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P6z82/)**.

Comment: Genius. Thank you. Exactly how I do it in photoshop as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `border-style` of `groove` is meant to do this.

Try

```css
hr {
    border-bottom: 2px groove;
}
```

The opposite of groove is `ridge`, and there are also styles `inset` and `outset` you can try for similar or other effects.

Comment: This didn't work when I tried it. What browsers is it compatible with? Can you create a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: @Elmer `groove` has been around "forever" since the earliest days of graphical browsers. What browser are you using where you don't see it? Take a look at the "**Display**" section in [this border tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/border.php) to see the different styles (groove is the 3rd). Note that a 1 pixel grooved border won't look grooved - it needs at least 2px to achieve the effect.